# Javascript (Jquery) code for next article in 'memory'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

First of all, I know of the (easier) possibilities of css for my question. But I am trying to learn JS (Jquery) so please bear with me.

**My plan:**
Menu-items (hooked to articles within my content division). Initially only the first article (#intro) is shown. All the articles within the #menu should be in an javascript array. When I hit *next* or *previous* another article corresponding with the chronology of the menu (articles) int he array should show.

this is a preview of what I want it to eventually look like (mind this is the 'bone-structure'): [image]

Please find my code below:

I am new to JS. I cannot figure out why the separate articles won't show. The first function of hiding everything initially works though.

**my html code:**

```
      <div id="wrapper">
  <header>

    <div id="logo" onclick="window.location.href='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=50×50&w=50&h=50'">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      <h1>Hartmeting voor fitte mensen</h1>
    </div>

  </header>

  <!-- Stappenplan Menu -->
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="#menu_a"> Introductie </a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu_b"> Het Probleem </a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu_c"> Stappenplan </a></li>
      <li><a href="#menu_d"> Hartmeting </a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <!-- HET STAPPENPLAN -->
  <div id="content">

    <!-- Intro Slide -->
    <article id="menu_a">
      <h2>Introductie</h2>
      <br>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=250×250&w=250&h=250" , alt="Intro Afbeelding" />
      </figure>
      <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
    </article>

    <!-- Slide 1 -->

    <article id="menu_b">
      <h2>Het Probleem</h2>
      <br>
      <figure>
        <img src="img/hetprobleem1.jpg" , alt="Eerste Afbeelding" />
      </figure>
      <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
    </article>

    <!-- Slide 2 -->

    <article id="menu_c">
      <h2>Hoe kan mijn hartslag meten?</h2>
      <br>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=250×250&w=250&h=250" , alt="Tweede Afbeelding" />
      </figure>

      <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>

    </article>

    <!-- Slide 3 -->

    <article id="menu_d">

      <h2>Hart Meten</h2>
      <br>
      <figure>
        <!-- Hartmeet tool -->
        <div>
          <div id="klik_Hart" class="heart">
            <h3 id="uitleg">

                                                        </h3>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>

          <!-- Einde hartmeet tool-->

      </figure>

      <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
    </article>

    <!-- ABOUT -->
    <!-- <div id="about">

                                        <p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </p>

                                    </div> -->


    <!-- Buttons -->
    <table id="volgorde">
      <th>
        <button class="button" name="previous">Vorige</button>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button class="button" name="next">Volgende</button>
      </th>
      <th>

        <!-- Checkbox Auto Slider -->
        <div class="auto_menu">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox">Auto Manual</label>
        </div>
        <!-- -->
      </th>

    </table>

    <div id="buffer"></div>
    <footer>
      <a href="#wrapper"> to the top! </a>
    </footer>
```

**My js code:**

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#content').hide();
 });

 var visible = $('#menu_a').first();

 var show_me = function(article) {

   visible.hide();
   visible = article;
   visible.show();
 }

 $("#menu_a").click(function(event) {

   var id_of_article = $(this).attr('href');
   var the_article = $(id_of_article);
   show_me(the_article);
   even.preventDefault();
 });


 $('#next').click(function(event) {
   var next = visible.next();
   if (next.length != 0) { // is there another article left?
     show_me(next);
   }
   event.preventDefault();
```

**my CSS Stylesheet:**

```
    #titel {
  color: #B0C4DE;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #708090;
  color: grey;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: 100%%
}

#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left top;
  border: 2px groove #191970;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

#content img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 450px;
}

#menu {
  font-weight: thin;
  color: grey;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 6.7%;
  font-size: 10pt;
}


/*#about{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    float: right;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1 {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #00008B;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFA07A;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
  padding: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
  color: blue;
}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

#volgorde {
  font-weight: thin;
  color: grey;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.button {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
  color: #FFA07A;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.heart {
  color: #FBF9FF;
  background-image: url("../img/hart4.png");
  background-size: 150px 150px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.heart:hoover {
  color: #FFA07A;
  background-color: grey;
}

#uitleg p {
  color: #FA8072;
}

#logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

#logo h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
}

#klik_ {
  text-align: center;
}

article p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}

#buffer {
  clear: both;
  height: 10%;
}

#stappen {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.auto_menu {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my JS? My intention was to put all the menu items into a variable and with the buttons 'next' / 'previous' display the content of the menu-items.

[JSFiddle Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/5pqyn62d/1/)

**EDIT**

```
var articleIds=['menu_a', 'menu_b', 'menu_c', 'menu_d'];

 var visible = $('#menu_a').first();

 var show_me = function(article) {

   visible.hide();
   visible = article;
   visible.show();
 }

 $("#menu_a").click(function(event) {

   var id_of_article = $(this).attr('href');
   var the_article = $(id_of_article);
   show_me(the_article);
   even.preventDefault();
 });

$('#next').click(function (event)
    {
        var next;
        if (visible.attr('#content') == articleIds[articleIds.length - 1])//article is the last one
            next = $('#' + articleIds[0]); //come back to first one
        else
            next = visible.next();
        show_me(next);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes in your code. some divs had no end tag and in images you 
put a ',' between src="" , alt="". between them must be only space.
And the script must be in the end of document.
And button next you wrote name='next' it must be id="next".
Then I removed the line `$('#content').hide();`
You must know $('#asdf') only works with id of elements. so must set id for your links:

```
<a id="Some_Name" href="#menu_a">Introductie </a>
```

and tested next button and it did some things to me but i do not know what you exactly want. 
And finally your code is this please test:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div id="logo" onclick="window.location.href='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=50×50&w=50&h=50'">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
            <h1>Hartmeting voor fitte mensen</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#menu_a">Introductie </a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu_b">Het Probleem </a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu_c">Stappenplan </a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu_d">Hartmeting </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
        <article id="menu_a">
            <h2>Introductie</h2>
            <br>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=250×250&w=250&h=250" alt="Intro Afbeelding" />
            </figure>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
        </article>
        <article id="menu_b">
            <h2>Het Probleem</h2>
            <br>
            <figure>
                <img src="img/hetprobleem1.jpg" alt="Eerste Afbeelding" />
            </figure>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
        </article>

        <article id="menu_c">
            <h2>Hoe kan mijn hartslag meten?</h2>
            <br>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=250×250&w=250&h=250" alt="Tweede Afbeelding" />
            </figure>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
        </article>
        <article id="menu_d">
            <h2>Hart Meten</h2>
            <br>
            <figure>
                <div>
                    <div id="klik_Hart" class="heart">
                        <h3 id="uitleg">asdfasdf
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </figure>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
        </article>
        <table id="volgorde">
            <th>
                <button class="button" name="previous">Vorige</button>
            </th>
            <th>
                <button class="button" id="next">Volgende</button>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="auto_menu">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox">Auto Manual</label>
                </div>
            </th>
        </table>
        <div id="buffer"></div>
        <footer>
            <a href="#wrapper">to the top! </a>
        </footer>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#content').hide();
    });

    var visible = $('#menu_a').first();

    var show_me = function (article)
    {

        visible.hide();
        visible = article;
        visible.show();
    }

    $("#menu_a").click(function (event)
    {

        var id_of_article = $(this).attr('href');
        var the_article = $(id_of_article);
        show_me(the_article);
        even.preventDefault();
    });


    $('#next').click(function (event)
    {
        var next = visible.next();
        if (next.length != 0)
        { // is there another article left?
            show_me(next);
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort! Well, no all the articles are shown below each other. The content area should be empty or show only the first article. And when I hit the 'next' button it should show the next article (chronologically according to the menu-items).

Comment: Pls see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/va2xeysk/1/ why does it show all my articles below each other and not just the first article? I added some code for the previous-button. But both next and previous don't work. Why is this?

Comment: But when i test your code all of articles are hidden. because they are in the hidden div id="content"

Comment: Meaning that I have to make the js code so that it will show contents, but hide all the articles and only show the first article (intro) initially and show the others only when I hit next button.

Comment: Yes in the link above i did this. check if this is what you want.

Comment: It works!! thanks bro. I am going to copy via webinspector your code and see what it does for me. One minute, brb

Comment: Thank you for all your help man, you really thought me how to use id's and how to make them sync with JS code. I am going to try to make the same code for the previous-button just the same as the next-button. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The next element of your last article is your table. if you want to check if your article is the last one create a list of your article ids:

```
articleIds=['menu-a', 'menu-b', 'menu-c']
```

So change this:

```
$('#next').click(function (event)
    {
        var next;
        if (visible.attr('id') == articleIds[articleIds.length - 1])//article is the last one
            next = $('#' + articleIds[0]); //come back to first one
        else
            next = visible.next();
        show_me(next);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I hope it helps you

Comment: do I put #content at the place if visible.attr('id')? and do I have to change the # in next = $('#' + articleIds[0]); ?   I assume this piece of code comes in place of the last two paragraphs of js code I have written right? Please see my Edit :) does that look good? because it does not work yet as it first shows all the articles and then does not react to the next/previous button.